# Xcode import .m "failed"

Tags: xcode, file, import, integer

I have a problem: In my project, I need pass an integer value from "Options.m" to "GameViewOne.m".  I try to import with the comand (#import "Options.m"), but it throws an error and doesn't build.

I think that is the same to #include "anyfile.h", but I am wrong.

Can you help me to import a .m file?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I try with other idea and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't import .m files. They contain code. The way to pass a value from one class instance to another class instance would be by implementing a method to do so.
I.e. something like

[mygameview setInteger:[myoptions getInteger]];

I strongly recommend reading a programming introductory text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value is constant, put it in the additional .h file and include it both in "Options.m" and "GameViewOne.m".